# Prevent automatic generation of action attribute in spring form

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a spring form and by default spring uses the current URL for the action attribute. 
Is there anyway I can prevent the action attribute to be generated? I don't want the action since I am using jquery to keep track of the form submission.

Is it possible?

Comment: It is the default behavior, btw what you are handling through jquery?

Comment: I do validation when the form is submitted, through jquery. That's why

Comment: No I mean you why you want to remove the action from remove?

Comment: Somehow, when the action attribute is present, the jquery code is not being executed. Only when the action attribute is absent. it executes fine.

Comment: Can you add your JSP code ?

Comment: Then there might be issue with the jQuery code, Post the code here